# Certificate Error: Mismatched Address

Tags: windows, iis, sql-server, internet-explorer

I installed certificate with the details:

```
Issued To: mnit.xyz.com
```

and I have actually 4 sites. that use this domain:

```
home.mnit.xyz.com

register.mnit.xyz.com

research.mnit.xyz.com

contact.mnit.xyz.com
```

I try to open: https://home.mnit.xyz.com [link name changed] and I get the certificate error.

I have 2 Questions:

1. Can I certificate be used for these sites?
2. Is my certificate wrong?

Please help. Thanks.

I had had a multiple site certificate " Multiple Site ".

Comment: If you are trying to use the same certificate for multiple subdomains, you need a [wildcard SSL certificate](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/what-is-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate-567).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I see your problem. You have been issued a wildcard certificate for `*.xyz.com` which allows infinite **subdomains**, however you are trying to access a subdomain of a subdomain which the certificate is not valid for.

`mnit.xyz.com` would be valid `home.mnit.xyz.com` is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what certificate you have. 
You could have a wildcard certificate and then it should work if it is issued for `mnit.xyz.com` or `xyz.com`. Most likely though you don't, and then you need to issue seperate cerificates for every domain.

Comment: I inquired in my company and they said we have a multiple site certificate ? I s that even a type?

Comment: That could be referring to a SAN certificate where you explicitly specify multiple domains which are covered by the certificate e.g. `www.example.com`, `example.com`, `www.example.net`

Answer (score 0):

To check the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) that MarkoPolo mentioned, open the certificate and view the details. The specific field name might vary a bit, but it should be something like Subject Alternative Name or Certificate Subject Alt Name. You'll see a list of alternate names for that certificate.